# How to properly convert to redux toolkit a pattern where the same action is dispatched/checked on several places

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

I am slowly migrating my app from plain redux to redux-toolkit.
One patter I noticed I have is as follows:

1. An async thunk that fetches stuff and dispatches start/complete/error actions
2. A middleware that reacts to the complete action
3. Other functions that also dispatch the complete action

Previously I converted other thunks to be a simple `createAsyncThunk` action thunk and react to the generated thunk states `fulfilled|pending|rejected`, however on this situation I need to be able to dispatch the fulfilled one from several places.
I don't think is idiomatic (nor a good idea) if I dispatch the `fulfilled` type manually by doing `dispatch({ type: myThunk.fulfilled, payload})`.

My guess is that I should create another normal sync action creator and dispatch that from the thunk, from the other several places and use that one to react to it on the store and the middleware and totally ignore the `thunk.fulfilled` state.
Is my assumption correct?

Comment: Can you give some examples of what the current code is doing?  What does the thunk and the middleware look like? What other scenarios require dispatching the `fulfilled` action separately?

Comment: I'm using firebase and the event that adds a new item to the list is virtually the same than getting one synced. Then I have a middleware that reacts to the creation of a new item to set the window title to the title of that item. And of course my thunk is just creating items and dispatching a successful creation action. I'll put more detailed examples later if you think they are needed

Comment: Hmm. My first thought is that the window title step probably is better suited for a React component `useEffect` hook.  If you do actually need to dispatch the `fulfilled` action separate from when the async thunk does it, the action creator is attached to the thunk itself - you can do `dispatch(myAsyncThunk.fulfilled(payloadHere))`.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea the fulfilled status was a function, I thought it was a string. I guess that is the reason you provide matchers. I want to keep the title change as a middleware because there are several places on the application that needs to set the title, and having it centralised is better than remembering every place I have to put it or go there every time I have to change it. However my question was more towards correctes and standard practices. Is it better to create a separate action creator and use that everywhere? I have the feeling that is more semantic, but I want your opinion.